# HTTPLiveHeaders equivalent for IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, http

Can anyone let me know if there is any equivalent for Internet explorer like HTTPLiveheader addon for firefox which captures and records all the HTTPrequests etc?

I have an windows application that opens an instance of IE and then makes a few requests, authenticates, uploads files etc. I want to monitor all these.

Thanks,
Pavan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at this blog [post](http://www.improve.dk/blog/2006/11/19/invaluable-ie-addon-tools). [ieHTTPHeaders](http://www.blunck.se/iehttpheaders/iehttpheaders.html) might be particularly useful. Also note that IE8 comes with a Developer Toolbar that has this functionality out of the box.